# Thunderbird cannot send emails

Tags: email, thunderbird, email-client

I started using Ubuntu 16.04 for my internship and I have no idea what I’m doing. So total noob here.

Basically, Thunderbird won't work. It won't send or receive messages. When I try to send a message, it says:

[image: error message screenshot]

Here is the config of the SMTP server of the account:

[image: config window screenshot]

I checked dovecot and postfix and they both function normally. Tried sending emails in the terminal and it worked but not on Thunderbird.

When I try to add another account and click re-test instead of done, it gives another error saying:

> Thunderbird failed to find the settings for your email account.

My domain is email.com.

Comment: In the server settings change port 25 to the default 465.

Comment: From your provider `email.com` you must have received instructions on how to set up outgoing mail. That includes the name of the SMTP server, its port, the username, and what kind of encryption to use.

Comment: same error still @RoVo

Answer (score 0):

As per email.com website, this should be your configuration:

```
Email.com (mail.com) SMTP Server    smtp.mail.com
SMTP port   465
SMTP security   SSL / TLS
SMTP username   Your full email address
SMTP password   Your Email.com password
```

Anycase try to use a configuration that already work for another user on the same network (under the same gateway/firewall).

If clicking "re-test" the issue is still present, and you are sure the configuration is correct, try again: may be it is a matter of thunderbird syncronization with email.com provider. (It happens also with other providers, in some cases synced after about 20 minutes of trying).

Comment: that's what i did at first then my boss came and changed it. said it wasn't the correct one

Comment: i tried it and same error "Thunderbird failed to find settings"